# Прогноз отдельного события(результат неизвестен) по данным предыдущих

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, машинное-обучение

Нужно предсказать кол-во людей (в процентах) с определенным настроением по данным известных дней.

Насколько он будет объективен, используя sklearn? Как это лучше реализовать?

```
          2018-04-06  2018-04-07  2018-04-08  2018-04-09  2018-04-10  2018-04-11  2018-04-12  2018-04-15  2018-04-16  2018-04-17  
angry            8.0        0.00        0.00       33.33        0.38         0.0        5.00         0.0        0.00        9.52
disgust          0.0        0.00        0.00        0.00        0.00         0.0        0.00         0.0        0.00        0.00
fear             8.0        0.00       38.89        8.33       48.11        14.0       18.33        40.0       20.00       28.57
happy            0.0        0.00        5.56        0.00        1.52         0.0        5.00         0.0        0.00        0.00
neutral         12.0       71.43        5.56       16.67       46.97        55.0       26.67        30.0       53.33       19.05
sad             68.0       28.57       50.00       41.67        2.65        30.0       45.00        30.0       26.67       42.86
surprise         4.0        0.00        0.00        0.00        0.38         1.0        0.00         0.0        0.00        0.00
```

UPD:
Обычно есть данные (X) и соответствующие им ответы (Y).
А вот тут, как мне кажется, нельзя разделить по такому принципу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы не стал ожидать сколько-нибудь приемлимого прогноза только на основании даты. Настроения людей будут в большей степени зависить от погоды (солнце, пасмурно, дождь), от каких-то новостей, от личных обстоятельств и т.д. Единственное что приходит на ум - это вычленить день недели в качестве отдельного признака, т.к. в пятницу и субботу настроение у людей обычно лучше, чем, скажем, в понедельник.

Кроме того вам следует транспонировать DataFrame, добавить дату в качестве числа (большинство алгоритмов машинного обучения не умеют работать с типом данных `datetime`) и добавить день недели в качестве признака (столбца):

```
df = (df.T
        .assign(date=(pd.to_datetime(df.columns).astype(np.int64)//10**9), 
                week_day=pd.to_datetime(df.columns).weekday)
        .reset_index(drop=True))
```

результат:

```
In [74]: df
Out[74]:
   angry  disgust   fear  happy  neutral    sad  surprise        date  week_day
0   8.00      0.0   8.00   0.00    12.00  68.00      4.00  1522972800         4
1   0.00      0.0   0.00   0.00    71.43  28.57      0.00  1523059200         5
2   0.00      0.0  38.89   5.56     5.56  50.00      0.00  1523145600         6
3  33.33      0.0   8.33   0.00    16.67  41.67      0.00  1523232000         0
4   0.38      0.0  48.11   1.52    46.97   2.65      0.38  1523318400         1
5   0.00      0.0  14.00   0.00    55.00  30.00      1.00  1523404800         2
6   5.00      0.0  18.33   5.00    26.67  45.00      0.00  1523491200         3
7   0.00      0.0  40.00   0.00    30.00  30.00      0.00  1523750400         6
8   0.00      0.0  20.00   0.00    53.33  26.67      0.00  1523836800         0
9   9.52      0.0  28.57   0.00    19.05  42.86      0.00  1523923200         1
```

столбцы `date` и `week_day` будут вашими входными данными (`X`), а остальные - вашими выходными / предсказываемыми данными (`Y`)

Comment: Там скорее стоит рассматривать мероприятия,проходящие в том месте и дни недели(т.к число прогнозируемого дня известно).Снова большое Вам спасибо!)

Comment: @potemin, ну, не зная "domain / business knowledge" трудно что-то еще было посоветовать... ;)

Comment: @potemin, пока я писал [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/857605/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-dataframe-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%be?noredirect=1#comment1382452_857605) вы удалили ответ...  Я хотел вам посоветовать привести такой пример данных, который бы позволил воспроизвести проблему/задачу и показать результирующий дата сет, основанный на приведенном примере данных